# Rails 3 Active Record and sums

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, sum, conditional-statements

I have the following code in my Rails 3 application.

```
@clinical_healthplan_spend = Clinical.select("ClientKey as client_key, PVID as animal_key, sum(Payments) as total_payments")
                                 .where("ClinicalText LIKE 'Paid by PET HEALTH' AND PVID != 44444")
                                 .order("sum(Payments) DESC")
                                 .group("animal_key")
```

I am trying to achieve the following:

1. Order the results by the highest total_payments first.
2. Limit the table by records with a total_payment value of at least 1500.

For the first requirement;

```
.order("sum(Payments) DESC")
```

Doesn't work and nor does

```
.order("total_payments DESC")
```

For the second requirement;

```
.where("total_payments > 1500")
```

doesn't work.

Am I putting the conditions in the right place, or is there a different way of doing these when using the sum option?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `where`, you have to use `having`. And in your `group` you have to include all the fields that don't have an aggregate. In this case `animal_key` and `client_key`. Other than that I don't see any problems with your code. This should work:

```
Clinical.select('ClientKey as client_key, PVID as animal_key, sum(Payments) as total_payments')
  .where("ClinicalText LIKE 'Paid by PET HEALTH' AND PVID != 44444")
  .group('animal_key, client_key')
  .having('sum(Payments) > 1500')
  .order('sum(Payments) DESC')
```

Comment: That worked, but could you explain "And in your group you have to include all the fields that don't have an aggregate."?

Comment: You want to show the sum (which is an [aggregate function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function)) of payments for the combination of `animal_key` and `client_key`. So you have to `GROUP BY` both `animal_key` and `client_key`. Do you understand?